# Removing First and Last Double Quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

I have set of `String`s where the first and last characters are double quotes. Below is an example.

```
String x = "‘Gravity’ tops the box office for 3rd week  | New York Post"
```

Some other strings will contain double quotes in the middle of the text, so I can't use `String.replaceAll()`. I just need to remove the first and last double quotes. How can I do this?

Comment: You _can_ use `replaceAll()` if you know about `^` and `$`.  Go and look up the Javadoc for the `Pattern` class.

Comment: Along with alternation (```|```).

Comment: Or just don't use regex just use String API to get your substring.

Comment: Am I the only one not seeing leading and trailing double quotes in that string?

Comment: Or alternatively you can use indexOf and lastIndexOf http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=225

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the `"` characters are always going to be the first and last ones, you don't need a regex. Just use `substring`:

```
x = x.substring(1, x.length() - 1)
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that catches the important information in the problem description.

Comment: but did not work with me what worked `console.log(someStr.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));` because i have teaser and other stuff and this was much accurate

Answer (score 7):

try this regex

```
s = s.replaceAll("\"(.+)\"", "$1");
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "\"‘Gravity’ tops the box office for 3rd week  | New York Post\"";
        String string = x.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");

        System.out.println(string);     
    }
}
```

it gives:

```
‘Gravity’ tops the box office for 3rd week  | New York Post
```

Comment: I'm not a Java person per say, but wouldn't `System.out.println(x)` also give the same output. Since there are no "'s in the string to replace? Or am I missing something magical about Java string literals?

Answer (score 2):

If the string does not have that quotes always and you are not sure whether it will be quoted or not, you can use the following regex;

```
str.replace(/^\"(.+)\"$/,"$1")
```

This may also be useful when getting `font-family` from stylesheets. Font family property may return values like `Arial` or `"Open Sans"`.

Comment: Zortext can you explain how that works?

Answer (score 0):

Try [org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils#strip(String str,String stripChars)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#strip(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
StringUtils.strip("‘Gravity’ tops the box office for 3rd week  | New York Post", "\""); // no quotes
StringUtils.strip("\"‘Gravity’ tops the box office for 3rd week  | New York Post\"", "\""); // with quotes
StringUtils.strip("\"\"\"‘Gravity’ tops the box office for 3rd week  | New York Post\"", "\"\""); // with multiple quotes - beware all of them are trimmed!
```

All give:

```
‘Gravity’ tops the box office for 3rd week  | New York Post
```

Answer (score -2):

The best thing you can do is

`str.Trim('"')`

Double quote is enclosed in two single quotes, and thats it.
This technique is not limited to just double quotes but you can do for any character.

Furthermore, if you wants to do the same thing only for either start or end character (not both) even then there is an option. You can do the same thing like

```
str.TrimEnd('"')
```

this removes only the last character
and

`str.TrimStart('"')`

removes only the only first(Start) character

Comment: that's not standard java, is it?