# how to remove first and last quotes for string in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am getting  a in strings and need to remove first and last quotes,please help

```
var a= "item.countryId ===3 && item.examId ===2 && item.streamId.includes(3) && item.createdName ===manoj "
```

i have tried these but not worked for me,
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873191/removing-first-and-last-double-quotes)

Comment: Your link example is in Java, which is not equivalent to Javascript.

Comment: Secondly, we need more information about the situation, because the best way to remove the double quotes from your code is to basically delete them.

Comment: Why are you getting code in a string? There are lots of problems with doing that. I also don't see the relevance of those React/Redux/arrays tags.

Comment: i am using this string to pass to filter an array,so i need to remove quotes

Comment: Looks like you are mixing Java & JavaScript. Instead of removing quotes write a function to filter array based on the above condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a function instead of passing filters as string.

```
const customFilter = (item) => (item.countryId ===3 && item.examId ===2 && item.streamId.includes(3) && item.createdName ==='manoj')
```